# How can I wait until the whole batch of requests are made and the promises are solved before I send the data on the callback function?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I have an object with 5 items, each of them will send an http request 3 times.
I save that in a

```
         var promise 
         var promise1 
         var promise2
```

In the end, I am resolving (trying) the promises using

```
Promise.all([promise, promise1, promise2]]
```

And then I send the data to a callback function.

I am using array.map() to do my task on that array, all the requests and Promise.all are happening inside that.

How can I wait until the whole batch of requests are made and the promises are solved before I send the data on the callback function?

```
async function requestJahrStatistic(jahreStatistic, callback){
Promise.all(
     jahreStatistic.map(async (item) => {
      var periods = getReportingPeriod(item.period);

      connection.statistic_id = item.statistic_id;

      connection.reporting_period = periods.prevYear;
      var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        sendHTTPRequest(item, function(result) {
          resolve(result);
        });
      });

      connection.reporting_period = periods.actualYear;
      var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        sendHTTPRequest(item, function(result) {
          resolve(result);
        });
      });

      connection.reporting_period = periods.nextYear;
      var promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        sendHTTPRequest(item, function(result) {
          resolve(result);
        });
      });

      Promise.all([promise, promise1, promise2]).then(async resolved => {
        var res = await resolved
        return res
      });
    })
  ).then(async resolved =>{
      var resp = await resolved;
      callback(resp)
  });
```

}

This was the last thing I tried before writing the question

Comment: Just `return` the `Promise.all` at the end of the `.map` callback

Comment: ^^ and then your `then` handler at the end doesn't need to be nearly so complicated. It can literally be `.then(callback)`. (You also don't need the `then` handler on the bottom `Promise.all` in the `map` callback at all. Just `return Promise.all([promise, promise1, promise2]);`

Comment: So what you guys are saying is that where I have my then, I can do .then(callback(res)? I dont think I get, sorry.

Comment: Side note: Surely `sendHTTPRequest` can fail. This code isn't handling that possibility at all. There's also no reason for the `map` callback to be `async`, since you're not using `await` within it.

Comment: @Fix3r - No, I meant literally what I said: `.then(callback);`. That passes `callback` into `then`, which means when the `Promise.all` promise resolves, it will call `callback` with the array of results.

Comment: FYI, I posted an answer then realized there was a problem in the code I hadn't considered, so I deleted it while I fixed that. I've undeleted it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with that code:

1. `requestJahrStatistic` shouldn't be `async` if it reports its results by calling a callback
2. You use this pattern in a couple of places:

   ```
   .then(async resolved => {
     var res = await resolved
     return res
   });
   ```

   That serves no purpose (unless... see #5) and can be completely removed.
3. There's no reason for the `map` callback to be `async`, as you're not using `await` within it.
4. You're repeating your logic wrapping `sendHTTPRequest` in a promise, and failing to handle errors in it. Don't repeat yourself, make a function for that.
5. It looks like `connection.statistic_id` and `connection.reporting_period` are used by the HTTP requests somehow. They shouldn't be, that's spooky action at a distance. :-) But if they are, then **none** of this can be in parallel since you have to wait for a request using a given `statistic_id` and `reporting_period` to complete before you can start the next.
6. You're not handling errors.

If I assume `connection.reporting_period` is used by the HTTP requests, that means they can't overlap, so none of this can be in parallel and you can't use `Promise.all` for it. You'd need something like:

If `connection.reporting_period` **isn't** used by the HTTP requests, this can all be parallel:

```
function sendHTTPRequestP(item) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sendHTTPRequest(item, result => {
            if (/*an error occurred*/) {
                reject(new Error(/*...*/));
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    })
}

// Completely serial because of spooky action at a distance with
// `connection.statistic_id` and `connection.reporting_period`
function requestJahrStatistic(jahreStatistic, callback) {
    Promise.resolve(async () => {
        const results = [];
        for (const item of jahreStatistic) {
            const periods = getReportingPeriod(item.period);
            connection.statistic_id = item.statistic_id;

            connection.reporting_period = periods.prevYear;
            const result1 = await sendHTTPRequestP(item);

            connection.reporting_period = periods.actualYear;
            const result2 = await sendHTTPRequestP(item);

            connection.reporting_period = periods.nextYear;
            const result3 = await sendHTTPRequestP(item);

            results.push([result1, result2, result3]);
        }
        return results;
    })
    .then(callback)
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle/report error, call `callback` with the appropriate error flag
    });
}
```

Or something along those lines. Note that what `callback` will receive is an array of arrays. The outer array will have as many entries as `jahreStatistic`; each of those entries will be an array of the results of the three HTTP calls.

If you can change things so that each operation takes arguments rather than spooky action at a distance (I see that sendHTTPRequest already has the `item` so can presumably get `statistic_id` from it, so we just have to pass `period`), you can make things parallel:

```
function sendHTTPRequestP(item, reporting_period) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sendHTTPRequest(item, reporting_period, result => {
            if (/*an error occurred*/) {
                reject(new Error(/*...*/));
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    })
}

function requestJahrStatistic(jahreStatistic, callback){
    Promise.all(
        jahreStatistic.map((item) => {
            const periods = getReportingPeriod(item.period);
            return Promise.all([
                sendHTTPRequestP(item, periods.prevYear),
                sendHTTPRequestP(item, periods.actualYear),
                sendHTTPRequestP(item, periods.nextYear)
            ]);
        })
    )
    .then(callback)
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle/report error, call `callback` with the appropriate error flag
    });
}
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: I am expecting to send back an array with 5 items and each item has 3 items.
That means, each request, for each id is made 3 times and builds that object I want to send to the client.

The problem is that even if I implement your solution, at the end I will only get an array of arrays but of the same statistic, all the others are being ignored.

This is the point I dont really get.

Comment: @Fix3r - That part is in code not included in your question, the "spooky action at a distance" of the `connection` properties. We can't help you with it without more information about them. (But they **really** shouldn't be used in that way.)

Comment: My problem is that I cant get three different results for each id.
At the end, I get like I have sent one request, multiple times... so looping using map or for doesnt make difference.

For example: jahreStatistic is an array with 5 items and I am making a http request 3 times for each of those items.
At the end, I get an array of results with 15 identical items, that is the problem.
Even if I implement your solution, the result is the same.

The questions I have now is, what I want to do is even possible?
Thanks for helping, T.J

Comment: @Fix3r - Yes, it's entirely possible. But not with the requests depending on information on `connection` like that. You'll need to fix that before you can really do anything else.

Comment: That is the problem, I guess...
Each request will have a specific report period and I have to send that together with the ID.
That is the API documentation, without that information from connection, I cant make the request.

Comment: connection:{
            user: process.env.USER,
            password: process.env.PASSWORD,
            action: process.env.ACTION,
            resource_type: process.env.TYPE,
            collector: process.env.COLLECTOR,
            statistic_id:"0141",
            reporting_period:"190000"
        },  //this would be one single request for a specific id. If I want to make a new request to get the info for a different period, so I have to send that objt again

Comment: I found a way to implement your answer and it works now.
I will accept as the right answer because of that and +1 for the review and explanations you gave me. Thanks, it really helps!